# Facebook integration: how to achieve non-canonical metadata scrape

Tags: php, facebook, canonicalization

So that I can consolidate likes, shares and comments across canonical and non-canonical presentations of my content I set  And use the canonical url of og:url on my non canonical pages.

Refer/compare
http://antsmith.net/poetry/cured
http://antsmith.net/poetry/cured/tag/mental-health

Thanks to help on an earlier question this now all works in terms of aggregating comments and likes.

But, on my non-canonical pages I extend the title.

Canonical title is of the form [section][item]
Non-canonical title is [section][item][context]

Now when adding a comment to the non-canonical page and 'also posting on facebook' the created post has the canonical title (and in fact the canonical url)

Even if I accept the argument that I shouldn't extend the title on the non-canonical pages, I can't accept that posts created by adding a comment to a non-canonical page must have the canonical url...

So is there anything that can be done about this? How do others manage to share the non-canonical context whilst maintaining the aggregation of comments across canonical/non-canonical pages?

Comment: Should I use my canonical URL in like/comments data-href but use my non-canonical url in og:url???

Comment: Well, setting og:url to the non-canonical restores the title etc when sharing the non-canonical link BUT adding a comment and posting to facebook ALWAYS posts the canonical link, not the actual page link...